# Opencart проблема с опциями

Tags: php, cms, opencart

Проблема следующая: на товаре более 30 опций, в фронте выводит в админку, захожу - белый экран, товар отредактировать невозможно.

Зашел в модель поставил лимит 20 опций - товар открывает.

В чем проблема? Может, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

CMS OpenCart 1.5.5.1

Буду очень блогодарен.

Comment: Думаю может нужно php_memory_limit увеличить сейчас 64м, что думаете?

Comment: Может быть дело в какой-то конкретной опции которая находится между 20 и 30? Также я бы глянул логи php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр `max_input_vars` увеличить надо. Сделать это можно или через файл `php.ini`, или `.htaccess` или в панели управления хостингом/сервером.